# How do you change the scrollbar style in an Angular Material table?

Tags: angular, angular-material

What's the typical way to change the scrollbar style in an Angular Material table like the one below? (I don't see any styling attributes that I could use when I go to inspect the element.)

[angular-table-issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPpMK.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your `mat-table` tag into a container like :

```html
<div class="container-list">
  <mat-table>
  ...
  </mat-table>
</div>
```

Then :

```css
.container-list {
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100%;
}

.container-list::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.container-list::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 30px;
  background-color: black; // Put your color
}

.container-list::-webkit-scrollbar-button,
.container-list::-webkit-scrollbar-track,
.container-list::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece,
.container-list::-webkit-scrollbar-corner,
.container-list::-webkit-resizer {
  display: none;
}
```